# Creating subscription for future Date

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, subscription, schedule

We are facing an issue with subscription schedule, We want to create a subscription with future date and it seems possible through scheduling.

However we want to know the how it can be done , as we are facing issues with the API

- We can create a schedule on existing subscription but when adding start_date to it the API throws error.
- There is no option to assign a schedule to existing subscription.
- When we create a schedule with future date it doesn't assign any subscription id.
- There is no webhook that can let us know when the subscription is created for a subscription schedule in future.

Answer (score 0):

For a Subscription that doesn't exist yet and you want to start at some future date, there are two options:

1. Use a [free trial period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652329/how-to-start-a-subscription-in-stripe-with-delay) that ends on the date you want the "real" Subscription to start.
2. Schedule your own servers to make a call on the given date to create the Subscription then.

Stripe doesn't provide a way to "make a request in the future". SubscriptionSchedules are for scheduling changes to existing Subscriptions.