# Stripe - Adjusting particular recurring payments

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am working on a project for a client, and need the ability to be able to change/adjust & skip payments for a user that is on a recurring monthly subscription.

For example let's say it's June, and the customer is subscribed to a $50 per month plan. How could I adjust the payment for August to be $30? I don't see any documentation around adjusting upcoming payments.

The only thought that comes to mind to implement this, is to run a scheduled function daily which checks a users account to see if their next payment should be more/less than the subscription amount. And then update their subscription back & forth via cron jobs.

Any other thoughts or how to implement, or know if there is a possible/standard way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to either look into [subscription schedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) or [up/downgrading subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade).

Comment: I'm currently up/down grading subscriptions via cron jobs which gets it done. However subscription schedules looks ideal for this, I hadn't previously seen this in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: If this was useful to you please accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer that you need:
You can control the time when the subscription actually starts (i.e. when Stripe will start billing the customer) by using the trial_end parameter in your subscription creation request. Simply set the value of the parameter to the timestamp of the exact time you wish Stripe to start automatically billing the customer.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652329/how-to-start-a-subscription-in-stripe-with-delay#:~:text=You%20can%20control%20the%20time,start%20automatically%20billing%20the%20customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652329/how-to-start-a-subscription-in-stripe-with-delay#:%7E:text=You%20can%20control%20the%20time,start%20automatically%20billing%20the%20customer).

Comment: This is not what I mean. If the subscription is already started, how do we adjust a payment for 3/6/12 months in the future..

Comment: Then, you have to work with Stripe hooks https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks